# encoding a record using protobuff

Tags: erlang, data-transfer, protocol-buffers

I am looking to encode a record data structure in erlang using protobuff for erlang. I haven't found a function to do so.

```
 rd(person, {name = "", phone = [], address}).
 A = #person{phone=[0,8,2,3,4,3,1,2], name="Robert"}.

  protobuffs:encode(1, A, bytes).
  ** exception error: bad argument
  in function  protobuffs:encode_internal/3
    called as protobuffs:encode_internal(1,
                                         #person{
                                          name = "Robert",
                                          phone = [0,8,2,3,4,3,1,2],
                                          address = undefined},
                                         bytes)

   How can I encode a record using protobuff?
```

This is the module, I am using to encode, https://github.com/basho/erlang_protobuffs

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't encode arbitrary records you just defined, that's simply not how Protocol Buffers work in any language.

You need to:

1. Define your message types in a `.proto` file (read Protocol Buffers documentation for the syntax, supported types, etc.).
2. Generate code for the desired language(s) from it. In this case, using `protobuffs_compile:scan_file(<path-to-your-proto-file>).` as shown in the README.
3. Use the generated code. It will include the `person` record and `encode_person` function.